# Jenkins build does not fail if project source code has syntax error?

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, visualsvn-server

Im new to Jenkins and I have setup Jenkins on remote server and my source controlling tool is visual svn , I integrate visual studio2013 with visualSvn and visual svn with Jenkin , 
then for testing purpose code my vs project (windows service project) with wrong syntax and commit to the svn, but when I build that with jenkin it does not fail is there any step to take before run the Jenkins build process?

Comment: We need a bit more info here. E.g. what are the build steps in jenkins. Which scripts are run. Normally Jenkins will mark the build as failed if a script executed returns a non-zero exit code, so that could be a first step, to try manually running whatever Jenkins is running, and check the exit code.

Comment: @pete im new to Jenkins could u please tell me how should I get the exit code ? thanks pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry Experts,
I'm new to Jenkins and I didn't configure the build steps properly , now it's done. with msBuild tool , thanks for all your time.

Answer (score 0):

Could you the configuration part of Jenkins, how you are running the job.